# How can I repaint() my JPanel in parallel with computations / in another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel, repaint

Okay so, I have an algorithm working as mentioned below, and I wanted to know how I could repaint in a separate thread instead of the Event Dispatch Thread:

```
Input an ArrayList of 2 Dimensional Point objects.
while(each point object has not been a starting point)
LOOP

   Arbitrarily choose a starting point
   Find the shortest path through all nodes
   Call repaint() on the JPanel that displays this path.

END LOOP
```

My question is, how do I set up another Thread so that every time a shortest path is calculated, it sends the path to the thread that repaints the JPanel? I want to do this because I feel like i'm wasting time repainting() and this could make the method much faster.

I'm guessing that I can't simply say:

```
new Thread() {
    void run() {
        myJPane.repaint();
    }
}.start()
```

...since that would create a new thread every single time. How do I logically do this?

Comment: please for why reason by using `new Thread() {` and not `Swing Timer`, is there somthing like as `OpenGL`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how I could use Swing Timer here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, use a `SwingWorker`.  A `SwingWorker` has methods for publishing results of long running operations and processing those results on the EDT.

So basically...

```
public class PathFinderWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Path> {
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Input an ArrayList of 2 Dimensional Point objects.
        while(each point object has not been a starting point) 
        LOOP
            Arbitrarily choose a starting point
            Find the shortest path through all nodes
            publish(path);

        END LOOP
    }

    protected void process(List<Path> paths) {
        // Process the results as required...
    }
}
```

The funny thing about `repaint` is, by it's design, it's one of the few methods that is actually thread safe.

That is, `repaint` asks the `RepaintManager` to repaint a give area.  The `RepaintManager` will, at some time in the near future, schedule a `paint` event onto the Event Queue, is is then processed by the Event Dispatching Thread...safely...

For more details, take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Answer (score 0):

Paint in the EDT, do your work in the other thread.  The EDT is the one that's meant to deal with the GUI -- trying to get another thread involved there is guaranteed to screw up.

So the real question is, how to pass a value or data-structure from the "worker" thread back to the UI for painting?

Probably the simplest data-structure I've seen recently for this was a chain of Nodes, each with a back-pointer to the previous Node. Since they're immutable this can safely be passed between threads for display.

Comment: Okay so in the class that does all the work - which I now understand must be in a separate thread - how do I go about calling repaint() so that it repaints in the EDT rather than in the separate thread? I'm not sure I quite understood your last paragraph (I'm really new to concurrency and threading, sorry)
Could you possible add a link explaining?

Comment: @Trust By it's nature, `repaint` always schedules the actually repaint back onto the EDT.  `repaint` simple asks the `RepaintManager` to paint an area.  The `RepaintManager` then schedules the paint event onto the event queue, which is processed by the EDT...

Comment: So would it be okay to simply call repaint() on the panel from a thread other than the EDT without doing anything else? Is it that simple?

Comment: @trust `repaint`, yes.  But beware, if the UI relies on anything that the thread is changing, you will need to synchronise these...

Comment: Okay...guess that means I have to read up on synchronization then.